# Why I get connection to server API failed due to Internet connection

Tags: flutter

My flutter app gives this arrow when loading. Why do I get:

> connection to server API failed due to internet connection.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

I am loading the app and try to use the location. When it comes to locating the place I am at that's the error I get.

Comment: could you provide the code please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.